# Redirect to another route after submission success

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, redux-form

I'm using redux-form and react-router.  Redux-form provides a method called `onSubmitSuccess` which is called after successful submission.  However, I don't have access to the router in that method.

How can I redirect to a new route using react-router after a successful submission?

Comment: What the limiting factor that doesn't allow `{ browserHistory }` to be imported from `react-router`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use container component for this. Once your form is submitted, dispatch an action and in that action use `browserHistory` to change or replace the route.

```
//container code
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return{
    onSubmit : () =>{
        dispatch(updateData())
   }
 }

}

//action code
 function updateData(){
    //update state if needed
    browserHistory.push(//changed route)
 }
```

Comment: Why do functions have to be so nested all the time? Would it not be better to call the push method directly in on submit? React is so confusing... still new to it obviously...